# How to unit test a method with a nested call to super class method?

Tags: java, junit

I have Java 8, JUNIT, and Mockito in my project, but I am still learning the unit testing art.So need your help.

In my scenario --> `class B extends Class A`

CLass B contains a public method `mOfB()`

CLass A contains a method `mOfA()`

I would like to JUnit my method `mOfB()`.

`mOfB()` contains a call to `mOfA()`. And `mOfA()` returns a `List<Employee>`

`Employee` is an object with few attributes in primitive datatype and a `Map<Depts, CostCentre>`

How should I approach JUnit testing here?

Comment: Not easy to test mOfA() in isolation. If possible change the class structure so that A does not extend B (A is a B)  but instead has a reference to it (A has a B) and then you can easily mock mOfB()

Comment: Difficulty of unit testing is one reason to favour composition over extension

Comment: "Don't use inheritance for the sake of testing" doesn't make any sense at all

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: like @Chris mentions in his comment it's best if you composed the B class to contain a reference to A class.

Having said that, one trick you can do is to extract your own code to a different method in class B and test that instead. 
Change this:

```
class B {
    @Override 
    String methodInheritedFromA() {
        return "ABC" + super.methodInheritedFromA();
    }
}
```

into that:

```
class B {
    @Override 
    String methodInheritedFromA() {
        return classBFunctionality() + super.methodInheritedFromA();
    }

    String classBFunctionality() {
        return "ABC";
    }
}
```

And test `classBFunctionality` method rather than `methodInheritedFromA`.

Comment: Thanks for this pafau, but unfortunately my Class B doesnot override methodInheritedFromA(), neither I intend to override it as that would change my business logic. or break regression somewhere.

Comment: Even if the method is not overridden you could make it contain *only* the composite call to methodOfA()+methodOfB, where methodOfB will be a testable method which has all unique functionality to class B. And unit test methodOfB().You could also introduce *test* inheritance, and your testOfB would extend testOfA, maybe composing the test somehow?